# Find & Replace all CSS styles Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm going over a sheet with 600 lines of html & css and its gonna take me a month to delete all the css by hand.. What is the regex for all instances of `<style + everything inside here + </style>` in google sheets??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<\s*style[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*style>
```

https://www.regexpal.com/index.php?fam=117599

Comment: actually i needed one including new lines this is the final version: https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=117600

Answer (score 0):

This was my final working regex in google sheets (including carriage returns and linefeeds):

```
<\s*style[^>]*>(.|\r|\n)*<\s*\/\s*style>
```